# how to perform inverse of raster::rotate

Tags: r, r-raster

The raster package provides a function called `rotate` that

> "rotates a Raster* object that has x coordinates (longitude) from 0
>   to 360, to standard coordinates between -180 and 180 degrees.
>   Longitude between 0 and 360 is frequently used in global climate
>   models."

But if we wish to perform the inverse function of this to transform a -180 to 180 longitude into a 0 to 360 one, then the function does not work, because all it does is to discard any data that originated from a longitude less than zero:

```
library(maps)
library(maptools)
library(raster)
world = map("world", fill=TRUE, col="transparent", plot=FALSE)
world = map2SpatialPolygons(world, world$names, CRS("+proj=longlat +ellps=WGS84"))
world = rasterize(world, raster(nrows=100,ncols=200, ext=extent(-180,180,-90,90)))

plot(world)
```

[image]

```
plot(rotate(world))
```

[image]

How do we perform the inverse of `rotate` to convert "standard coordinates" ranging from -180 to 180 into 0 to 360 coordinates?

Comment: It is its own inverse, or at least it used to be

Comment: @mdsumner of course, that is what one would expect. But as my example shows it isn't now, although you could be correct that it once was.  The documentation suggests that it is only intended to work in one direction, so I dont think this is a bug so much as a missing feature.

Comment: Yes sorry it was just a comment :)  FWIW I preserved the old behaviour here, because it was much easier than updating all the uses of it: https://github.com/AustralianAntarcticDivision/raadtools/blob/3c92c6a6873a550773ff9e583e009bc1b62020be/R/utils.R

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This should do the trick:

```
w2 <- shift(rotate(shift(world, 180)), 180)
plot(w2)
```

[image]